# how to grep the word between symbols using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep the word between the symbols as shown below in an array.

`my $string = "hi how r u<what is your name>what is your age";`

i need to grep as

```
$str = what is yourname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use capturing groups like below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = "hi how r u?what is your name?what is your age";
my @str = $line =~ m/\?([^?]*)\?/g;
print "@str\n";
```

Output:

```
what is your name
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, in Perl:

```
$string =~ /\?(.+)\?/;
$result = $1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string on this metacharacter.

```
my @results = split /\?/, $string;
print $results[1];
```